# looking for a tool to emulate different internet browsers

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I am looking for a tool or a way to view my website on different browsers, such as IE7 and above and different versions of firefox.

I am new to CSS, but I installed some software on my PC that does it for me. It made problems and I had to reinstall my Windows. So I prefer to have some web application to achieve the same goal, and show reliably, how my website looks like on IE8 for example.

Comment: Sorry to be a downer, but the best way to ensure cross-browser compatibility is probably to download browsers and test it yourself. If you have IE9, you can easily switch to IE8 or IE7-mode and test stuff, by clicking F12 and choosing which browser version you'd like to emulate.

Comment: its is always better to test on a real browser.

Comment: Or alternatively (to be absolutely sure!) have a bunch of virtual machines. May be a bit of overkill though.

Answer (score 4):

An online solution like [Browserstack](http://www.browserstack.com/) could be useful in this case. You can test your web application in different browsers and different versions of browsers without the need to install them yourself.

Comment: @DmitryMakovetskiyd you get 60 minutes of testing free. Why would you expect a service like this to be free?

Comment: Those 60 minutes are nice if you just need to do some quick testing, if you want to do more, there's also several plans to choose from I think. I haven't found a service like this for free (except one that barely supported any browser). The only alternative is to set up virtual machines, which is a lot of work :(

Answer (score 2):

More online browser sites:

http://spoon.net/browsers/
http://browsershots.org/
http://www.crossbrowsertesting.com/

Answer (score 1):

Try http://www.my-debugbar.com/wiki/IETester/HomePage for IE 5.5 up, the emulator isn't always perfect but better than most. Most other major browsers have turned to rapid release fixes so if the css is working in a standards compliant browser now, it should in the future.

Answer (score 1):

This is good for IE testing http://www.my-debugbar.com/wiki/IETester/HomePage
But as the others have said you can't better testing on the real thing.

Comment: what about paid website like the Browserstack, offered by firvedigit

Answer (score 1):

The other way is to use Virtual machines but this involves installing something like windows XP and configuring snapshots for the different versions of IE/firefox/chrome.

You can do this with virtualBox - https://www.virtualbox.org/

This is all you need to do if you site is hosted on the web however(read below) :

If you test your website locally you can then run a small webserver on your main machine so you can access it on the virtual machine.

You can use XAMMP for this - http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp.html